# Transcript error, college unresponsive - how to handle?

Tags: transcript-of-records

I applied to graduate school this spring, and discovered that my undergraduate transcript has a substantial error: it omits one of my majors.

I contacted the university registrar, who indicated the omission was caused by a "system" issue that prevents listing a 3rd major if the student thas one. (They said their new system won't have this issue in the future, which doesn't help me at all.)

The registrar also pointed to a note on the bottom of the transcript that says I was "approved to pursue" the three majors. But, the comment is dated 2 years before graduation, and "approved to pursue" doesn't mean "completed," so I don't think this is sufficient, especially given the conspicuous blank spot next to where the third major would be listed.

Since replying to my first email right away, the registrar hasn't replied in weeks. They have not indicated that they plan to correct the issue.

**How do I get the college to correct my transcript, preferably soon enough to submit to the graduate school?**

Comment: You contact them: Dean, Head of Dept etc etc , we cannot help.

Comment: What is the extent of the error? Is only the name of the major missing, or are the courses you took for the major also missing?

Comment: @GoodDeeds The courses are there. The name of the major is missing. There's a slot for "Social Sciences" where a major would normally go, but it's just blank.

Comment: I'd suggest including your third major in your CV with a footnote quoting (verbatim) the registrar's email about the system issue. Anyone who wants to verify it can check with the registrar or ask you to forward that email.

Comment: One might point out that it is likely that the registrar is working from home which may impact their ability to try and mess with the system. Is the 3rd major the primary one for you graduate school application, or not? If not why does it really matter - they can see that you took a bunch of courses in the area. From many colleges that might at best be listed as a concentration, or not noted at all.

Comment: @JonCuster - The unlisted major is relevant for admission. (One of the listed majors is not.) To make sure I understand, are you saying that some colleges don't list majors on transcripts? I'm not just talking about a collection of courses, but a formally defined major that I have.

Comment: @MPJ - Many only allow one major. Some have the concept of minors or concentrations or certificates in addition to one major. Some allow multiple declared majors, and may or may not have minors or concentrations or certificates in other areas. Some (St. Johns) only have one major for everyone. It is a weird world out there.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions. First, I think that having three "majors" is pretty rare, so a system error omitting the possibility would be easy to make.

Second, I doubt that if you are good enough, then the third major isn't going to put you "over the line" in any application when two won't. (Caveat below)

Third, just explain it somewhere else in your application materials, such as your CV or cover letter, and *also* ask that the registrar will back you up if asked. Alternatively, have a faculty letter writer make it clear on your behalf. It is best if someone else, rather than yourself only, makes the statement so that it gains credibility.

Caveat: If that third major is your specific field of interest in graduate school, then you may need to have a letter from the registrar as part of your materials. Though, if you are in the US, even that probably wouldn't be essential as it isn't an absolute requirement that you continue in grad school in the studies you did as an undergraduate. Other places are a bit more strict, perhaps.